# Love2d game keeps on closing and giving 'Aborted core dumped' message in terminal (Linux Mint 20.2 Cinnamon)

Tags: lua, love2d

when i try to run the game that i am building with `love .` in terminal, i get `Aborted (core dumped)` in some occasions. But when i export it in .exe and play in windows, it does not crash.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `lovec .`

This is required on Windows for making the love program redirect output to your terminal. If you don't do it, you won't be able to check any kind of error.

Comment: I am building it in linux and lovec . command i not available

Comment: You should then explain what is really happening then. It is misleading as anyone would expect for you to be under windows.

Which occasions do you get Aborted? This is usually caused by trying to write into null memory. I believe that you may be accessing a C/C++ object from lua?

Comment: for example with this game that i made in love2d - https://shubhrok.itch.io/escape-the-quake , on trying to run the game with main.lua file using love . it gets aborted. But the .exe runs pretty well without any issues

Comment: For me it didn't occur any kind of abortion. Maybe you just need to update some old library version under your linux.